# Type inference in Scala. How does it work in this case?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

I'm experementing with `fs2.Stream` and faced some misunderstanding about type inference. Let's say that we have the following code:

```
import cats.effect.IO

val ios = IO(List(1, 2, 3))
val s: fs2.Stream[IO, Int] = fs2.Stream.eval(ios).flatMap(l => 
  fs2.Stream.emits(l)
) //compiles OK, but why?
```

And it compiles fine. But I don't understand why it the type is `fs2.Stream[IO, Int]`? Here is the signature:

```
def flatMap[F2[x] >: F[x], O2](f: O => Stream[F2, O2]): Stream[F2, O2] // F = IO?
def emits[F[x] >: Pure[x], O](os: Seq[O]): Stream[F, O]
```

So [`emits`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L2310) returns a `fs2.Stream[Pure, Int]`, but [`flatMap`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L789) of `fs2.Stream[IO, Int]` wants `F2[x] >: F[x]` where `F = IO`, but `F2 = Pure`. `Pure[x] >: IO[x]` is not correct...

How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So emits returns a fs2.Stream[Pure, Int]

No, it doesn't.

1. Given expected type of `s`, the expected type of `l => fs2.Stream.emits(l)` is `List[Int] => fs2.Stream[IO, Int]`, so
2. the expected type of `fs2.Stream.emits(l)` is `fs2.Stream[IO, Int]`, so
3. `F` in the signature of `emits` is inferred to be `IO`.

Comment: But how about the constraint `F[x] >: Pure[x]` in the signature of `emits`? `IO[x] >: Pure[x]`?

Comment: Yes, because `type Pure[A] <: Nothing` and therefore `<:` any type at all. (I actually had to spend a bit of time finding where `Pure` is defined).

Comment: Ah now I see, thanks. But it seems to me a bit overabstracted. As it is specified in docs `Indicates that a stream evaluates no effects`. `Id[A]` also seems to fit this purpose...

Comment: And add implicit conversions from `Id[A]` to `F[A]`? I would expect it to be less usable, though I don't have a strong opinion on this.